# Rails: accessing field value from model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, field

Where `title` is a field on the table in the database, why does calling `@title` return `nil`?

Unbelievably, accessing model fields from inside a method on that model is undocumented.

Comment: There's no need for two questions on the same thing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111163/rails-accessing-field-value-from-model-method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think about how you would access the info from outside the model:

```
model_instance.field_name
```

Therefore, from within the model you simply call

```
field_name
```

you can call instance methods from within that instance.